# Drupal: load the pages only when the page scrolls down

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there a plugin for Drupal to load images as the user scrolls down the page.

Such as: mashable.com ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I found a module http://drupal.org/project/lazy_image_loader that hopefully does the trick. I haven't tested it yet, but I'm certainly interested too. Let us know if it works as expected!

Comment: thanks! However it doesn't work. But the original plugin doesn't work with latest browsers update... http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: For example, this page doesn't work: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

Comment: I also just tested in Firefox (3.6.10) and it works there (I mean the example page you gave ...)

Comment: well, did you check the Firebug window ? It seems that the images are loaded at the beginning anyway. And then reloaded again when you scroll down. Anyway in Safari doesn't work right ?